# Xamarin binding to objC payment api always returns timeout from api

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Hi We have created a Xamarin binding to objC payment api. This binding project was working fine until we used iOS SDK 6.1 and now its breaking for iOS SDK 7.1 and always returns timeout from api.

```
Sep 22 08:13:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : activationUrl in use : https://******************************************
Sep 22 08:13:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : ----->Called initiate Session 
Sep 22 08:13:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : parameters used 
Sep 22 08:13:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : Key - DF12 & Value - ****** 
Sep 22 08:13:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : Key - DF11 & Value - ****** 
Sep 22 08:13:20 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S syncdefaultsd[686] : (Note ) SYDAccount: no account 
Sep 22 08:13:20 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S syncdefaultsd[686] : (Note ) SYDPIMAccount: no account (null) 
Sep 22 08:13:20 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S syncdefaultsd[686] : (Note ) SYDAlwaysOnAccount: no account (null) 
Sep 22 08:13:53 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S backboardd[31] : ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=0.0500 
Sep 22 08:13:55 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S backboardd[31] : ALS: SetDisplayFactor: factor=1.0000 
Sep 22 08:13:57 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084437.123934]: Client MobileMail set type to normal application 
Sep 22 08:13:57 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084437.124622]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: sharingd apsd networkd 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.721643]: WiFiLocaleManagerCheckLocale: trying to determine locale... 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.722217]: WiFiManagerCoreLocationGetCachedLocation: getting cached location... 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.726062]: __WiFiLocaleManagerGetLocaleFromMcc: finding iso country code for mcc 404 .... 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.726653]: Starting Low Accuracy Location Monitoring, locationMonitoringTimeout=60.000000 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.727160]: WiFiManagerCoreLocationStartLocationUpdates: starting location updates... 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.727587]: Location Monitoring successfully started with accuracy=3000.000000meters 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.728692]: __WiFiLocationServiceManagerEventCallback, got cb dict { 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : eventType : 0 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : location : <+17.44007333,+78.37926585> +/- 86.49m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/22/14, 8:12:55 AM Central Daylight Time 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : } 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.733194]: __WiFiLocationServiceManagerProcessLocationAvailableEvent: isValidHighAccuracyLocation 1, isValidLowAccuracyLocation 1 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.733642]: __WiFiLocationServiceManagerProcessLocationAvailableEvent: give low accuracy callback 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.734005]: __WiFiLocaleManagerGetLocaleFromLocation: <+17.44007333,+78.37926585> +/- 86.49m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/22/14, 8:12:55 AM Central Daylight Time 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.737186]: locale from bounding box Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.737526]: new locale: , locale: 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.737866]: Stopping Low Accuracy Location Monitoring 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.738215]: Location Monitoring stopped 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.738544]: WiFiManagerCoreLocationStopLocationUpdates: stopping location updates... 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.740562]: Stopping Low Accuracy Location Monitoring 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.740988]: CLMonitoring is already stopped 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.749325]: Async scan requested by "locationd" for 1 iterations with maxage=0 priority normal on en0 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.749694]: Enqueuing command type: "Scan" pending commands: 0 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.749988]: Dequeuing command type: "Scan" pending commands: 0 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.750235]: Attempting Apple80211ScanAsync on en0 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.791170]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd" 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.797443]: WiFi unquiescing requested by "locationd" 
Sep 22 08:14:07 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084447.999343]: Completed Apple80211ScanAsync on en0 (0) 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.001306]: Async scan request completed for "locationd" (0) 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.007309]: Async scan requested by "locationd" for 1 iterations with maxage=0 priority normal on en0 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.007845]: Enqueuing command type: "Scan" pending commands: 0 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.008259]: Dequeuing command type: "Scan" pending commands: 0 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.008624]: Attempting Apple80211ScanAsync on en0 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.484228]: Completed Apple80211ScanAsync on en0 (0) 
Sep 22 08:14:08 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S wifid[40] : WiFi:[433084448.485499]: Async scan request completed for "locationd" (0) 
Sep 22 08:14:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : output parameters 
Sep 22 08:14:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : Key - DF39 & Value - 4900 
Sep 22 08:14:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S Sample[681] : ----->DONE initiate Session 
Sep 22 08:14:11 Xamarin-Team-Test-Device-5S backboardd[31] : HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'Sample' access to protected services is denied.​
```

Comment: Can anybody explain HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'Sample' access to protected services is denied.

Comment: Can you post some code? Is this on a device or the simulator? Is the fact you updated Xcode and the iOS SDK the main cause for this?

Comment: yes i update Xcode and xamarin. HID: The 'Rate Controlled' connection 'Sample' access to protected services is denied error was not becoz of the xamarin binding to objc. I was using the main thread for the api once i did it in the separate thread it started working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the main thread for the api once i did it in the separate thread it started working. I need to figure out that how new thread is making it work.